# Is it possible to combine IF() OR() and AND() function in Excel with three output arguments?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am at a loss and I hope an Excel magician can save my day. :)

What I want to do:

- Leave field as "In progress" if due date more than 2 days away
- Change field to "Attention needed" if due date less than 3 days away
- Change field to "Overdue" if due date has passed

This is what I tried, I don't see where I could be wrong:

```
`=IF(OR(AND("In progress", [@[Deadline on]]-TODAY()>0, "Overdue"),AND("In progress", TODAY()-[@[Deadline on]]<3,"Attention needed")),"In progress")
```

Is it not possible to combine them like this? It always worked for me using multiple ifs but that doesn't work here either.

Thank you so so much!
Jess

Comment: `IF([@[Deadline on]]-TODAY() > 2, "In Progress", IF([@[Deadline on]]-TODAY()<=2, "Attention needed", "Overdue"))` ?  Not sure why `AND` and `OR` are needed here.

Comment: thank you. but it's not working, it says attention needed although it's overdue. also I just want anything to happen if it is "in progress", if it is "open" or "closed", nothing should happen. am I missing something?

Comment: Oh shoot. Of course it does. Instead: `IF([@[Deadline on]]-TODAY() > 2, "In Progress", IF([@[Deadline on]]-TODAY()<0, "Overdue", "Attention Needed"))`

Comment: `=IF(AND("In progress", [@[Deadline on]]-TODAY() > 2), "In Progress", IF(AND([@[Deadline on]]-TODAY()<=2, [@[Deadline on]]-TODAY()>0), "Attention needed", "Overdue"))` I got it now, however, how do I get it to stay as "open" if "open" and "completed" if "completed"? thanks so much!

Comment: It can't retain a value that it already has. Like it can't be both a value AND a formula. Is tehre another column where "Open" "Completed" logic/formula/value is?

Comment: you make it seem so easy :D I appreciate your help!

Comment: well, with the if condition it is already retaining in progress if it's in progress, can't it be like an overarching condition if "in progress" then do all this and if not then -leave as is-?

Comment: As @JNevill said, a cell formula can't check the status of itself, otherwise it would be circular. A cell formula can check the status of values in other cells. So you would need at least one other column as a criterion that you could use as a sort of override.